# QT even processing while waitForConnected is running

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, event-handling

I have loop that is supposed to try to connect to each IP from range:

```
for(...){

socket->connectToHost(addres,port);
do stuff....
if(socket->waitForConnected(2000))
{
do stuff...
  if(socket->waitForReadyRead(1000))
  {
   do stuff...
  }
  else do stuff...
}
do stuff ......
}
```

During connection atempts UI freezes, because there is no event processing in the meantime. I tried to add QCoreApplication::processEvents(); inside the loop, however it still freezes for long time during waitForConnected, and I also tried to use timers, but this also wont work as QT needs event processing to use timers in the first place. Is there any way to provide event processing (prevent UI from freezing) during conection, or using some non-blocking alternative for waitForConnection?

Comment: Why don't you use appropriate signals, such as readyRead for example, in this case your GUI will not be freezed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to use `QTcpSocket` in an asynchronous mode by connecting the signals of the socket to relevant slots :

```
connect( socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(onConnected()) );
connect( socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(tcpReady()) );
connect( socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
    this, SLOT(tcpError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)) );
```

And handle your application logic in the slots :

```
void MyClass::onConnected()
{
    ...
}
void MyClass::tcpError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)
{
    ...
}
```

You can also use a local event loop using `QEventLoop` and connect the signals `connected`, `error`, ...  of your `QTcpSocket` to the quit slot of `QEventLoop`. This way when the socket is connected or an error is occured, the local event loop quits and the rest gets executed :

```
socket->connectToHost(addres,port);

QEventLoop loop;
loop.connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), SLOT(quit())); 
loop.connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), SLOT(quit())); 
loop.exec();

//...
```

I should not that it's the standard pattern for "blocking wait without blocking the UI".

Answer (score 0):

Please write out 100 times 'I must not wait in GUI event-handlers'.

Use async signals or thread off the comms.

Comment: Can you write something more abaut that async signals, what is diferent in them comparing to normal signals ? and how i can create one of them ?